# Personal regex in spring security grails

Tags: regex, grails, spring-security

My goal is to have a personal regex in my conf file so when i update/rewrite the plugin i always have my regex working

In password validator i found this:

```
static boolean checkPasswordRegex(String password, command) {       
    def conf = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig

    String passValidationRegex = conf.ui.password.validationRegex ?:
            '^.*(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&]).*$'

    password && password.matches(passValidationRegex)   
}
```

But i want this regex '^.*(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&+-]).*$'

How can I handle this?

Comment: Which version of spring-security plugin do you use ?

Comment: @emilan i use spring-security core 2.0 and spring-security-ui 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see from your example, you have to put your regex into

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.password.validationRegex = '^.(?=.\d)(?=.[a-zA-Z])(?=.[!@#$%^&+-]).*$'
```

in your `Config.groovy`

Comment: Great answer! However, where exactly should I load this? I appreciate your answer! Cause it does not work, yet...